# Can I use Ruby in-built RSS module to read atom feed?

Tags: ruby, parsing, feed, atom-feed

I am in an environment where I don't have access to install any gems. I only have standard ruby (version:1.8.7) installation.

I am trying something like this:

```
require 'rss/1.0'
require 'rss/2.0'
require 'open-uri'

source = "http://www.example.com/feed.atom" # url or local file
content = "" # raw content of rss feed will be loaded here
open(source) do |s| content = s.read end
rss = RSS::Parser.parse(content, false)
```

When I am parsing the content, I am getting nil. So I am wondering if in-built RSS module supports parsing an atom feed.

Comment: Did you know that you can use gems without installing them in the system directory? You can put them in your project, for example, using the GEM_HOME environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you look under [RSS::Maker](http://www.ensta.fr/~diam/ruby/online/ruby-doc-stdlib/libdoc/rss/rdoc/classes/RSS/Maker.html) what it can parse.

Comment: It doesn't mention ATOM in the list. So I am assuming the answer is, it doesn't support it.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, consider trying the [nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/) gem.

Comment: I dont see any reason why the OP cannot install nokogiri on another machine or download from https://github.com/tenderlove/nokogiri then transfer to the OP's environment, though.